# How can i send parameters from one template to another template/view in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Ok, so i have in my views.py these functions

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return newFunction(request)
    return render(request,'user/main.html')

def newFunction(request):
    num = request.POST["number"]
    let = request.POST["letter"]
    context = {'num':num,'let':let}
    return render(request,'user/test.html',{'c':context})
```

And that main.html looks like this

```
{%extends 'base/base.html'%}

{%block title%}Main{%endblock%}

{%block content%}


<form method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="text" name="letter">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>


{%endblock%}
```

The urls.py

```
path('index/',main,name='main'),
path('test/',newFunction,name='test'),
```

As you can see, i enter the main.html page and a form appears, asking me for a number and a letter. I enter these 2 inputs and when clicking the submit, it redirects me to another html and show me the letter and number. The problem is that the url still shows user/index.html, not user/test.html

How can i do this? i want to basically click the submit and send all the values to another template but changing the url in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax for do that. You can use form either, but ajax is more appropriate for just passing data to view.

Just sending ajax request with some data, and send it to your target view.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{% url 'test' %}",
    data: {
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
        "num": 'number',
        "let": 'letter'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(e) {
        // success after receive response
    }
});
```

Of course you can send it with `form`. Just add your target url in `action`.

```
<!-- add your target url in action -->
<form method="post" action="{% url 'test' %}">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="text" name="letter">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! the form solution was the one that worked for me :D but i will consider using the ajax one because im implementing it in another templates anyway

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled on the frontend, using the `action` attribute within the opening `<form>` tag whose value should be the URL you want the form's data to be `POST`'d to on submit. Your opening `<form>` tag can be changed to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="/user/test.html">
```

Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data